# How to set maxDate is last day of december on current year?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this date range datepicker :

```
$(function () {
  //date picker range 
  $(function () {         
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        //defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate: MinDateManipulation(),
        beforeShowDay: DisableMonday,
        maxDate: '+2M',
        numberOfMonths:1
      })
      .on("change", function () {
        to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
      }),
      to = $("#<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        //defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShowDay: DisableMonday,
        maxDate: '+2M',
        numberOfMonths:1
      })
      .on("change", function () {
        from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
      });
    function getDate(element) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
      } catch (error) {
        date = null;
      }
      return date;
    }
  });
```

It work when i tried to disable date from 2 months after current date, but the purpose is, to disable date in January 1st every next year after current year.

***for example : current date [11/3/2018]***

I want to disable date to chose after last day of December every current year, with maxDate `[31/12/2018]`.

But how do we set dynamically for the value of the maxDate? without update the value of the year manually with my daterange condition script?

Comment: I assume this is jQuery UI DatePicker? If so, look at http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate it accepts a number of days. If you know today and the date you want as your max, you could calculate the number of days dynamically. Or use a function that returns a Date, Number or String.

Comment: yes its Jquery UI DatePicker. i've tried some like maxDate: new Date(someVariabel, 1,1) but its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear the range you are trying to capture, yet you can do a lot with what you already have.

One way would be to set it to a string format:

```
var yr = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy", new Date());
var dec31 = "12/31/" + yr;
....({
  maxDate: dec31,
})
```

this will get the current Year (2018) and create a string that can be used as the max date: `12/31/2018`. This will remain dynamic and update each year.

You could also define a number of days in the year as holidays. Lots of things you can do.

Maybe this example will help clear up a few things.

```js
$(function() {
  var holidays = {
    2018: {
      11: {
        12: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Veterans Day Observed"
        ],
        22: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Thanksgiving Day"
        ]
      },
      12: {
        25: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Christmas Day"
        ],
        31: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "New Year's Eve"
        ]
      }
    },
    2019: {
      1: {
        1: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "New Year's Day"
        ],
        21: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Martin Luther King Jr. Day"
        ]
      },
      2: {
        18: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Presidents' Day"
        ]
      },
      5: {
        27: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Memorial Day"
        ]
      },
      7: {
        4: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Independence Day"
        ]
      },
      9: {
        2: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Labor Day"
        ]
      },
      10: {
        14: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Columbus Day"
        ]
      },
      11: {
        11: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Veterans Day"
        ],
        28: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Thanksgiving Day"
        ]
      },
      12: {
        25: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Christmas Day"
        ],
        31: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "New Year's Eve"
        ]
      }
    }
  };

  function disableDays(d) {
    var result = [true, ""];
    var yr = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy", d),
      mo = $.datepicker.formatDate("m", d),
      dy = $.datepicker.formatDate("d", d);
    if ($.datepicker.formatDate("D", d) == "Mon") {
      result[0] = false;
    }
    if (holidays[yr] !== undefined) {
      if (holidays[yr][mo] !== undefined) {
        if (holidays[yr][mo][dy] !== undefined) {
          console.log("Holiday:", yr, mo, dy);
          result = holidays[yr][mo][dy];
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    from = $("#client-id-1").datepicker({
      //defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      minDate: 0,
      beforeShowDay: disableDays,
      maxDate: '+1y',
      numberOfMonths: 1
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#client-id-2").datepicker({
      //defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      beforeShowDay: disableDays,
      maxDate: '+2m',
      numberOfMonths: 1
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });

  function getDate(element) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }
    return date;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Client 1: <input type="text" id="client-id-1"></p>
<p>Client 2: <input type="text" id="client-id-2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and use my code to get max date:

```
function _getMaxDate() {
    const today = moment().startOf('day')
    const lastDayOfYear = moment().endOf('year').startOf('day')

    return lastDayOfYear.diff(today, 'days')
}
```