# need to disable Holidays and day in datepicker contact form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, user-interface, jquery-ui, plugins

I saw many solutions but cant disable Sunday Monday and holidays on my contact form 7.trying this solution using and id placing it in functions and footer files but it still displays.Code is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            return [date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 3 || date.getDay() == 4 ||
            date.getDay() == 5 || date.getDay() == 6, ""]
        }
    });
</script>

<label> <span style="color: #000080;"><strong>Your Appointment Date</strong></span>(required)
[date* date-163 id:datepicker]</label>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future, it is best to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also it is best to search before posting a question. Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128077/how-to-set-maxdate-is-last-day-of-december-on-current-year

Comment: It seams you have created a `date` input type. This will not work well with datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Duplicate: [How to set maxDate is last day of december on current year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128077/how-to-set-maxdate-is-last-day-of-december-on-current-year)

Consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  var holidays = {
    2019: {
      1: {
        1: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "New Year's Day"
        ],
        21: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Martin Luther King Jr. Day"
        ]
      },
      2: {
        18: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Presidents' Day"
        ]
      },
      5: {
        27: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Memorial Day"
        ]
      },
      7: {
        4: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Independence Day"
        ]
      },
      9: {
        2: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Labor Day"
        ]
      },
      10: {
        14: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Columbus Day"
        ]
      },
      11: {
        11: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Veterans Day"
        ],
        28: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Thanksgiving Day"
        ]
      },
      12: {
        25: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "Christmas Day"
        ],
        31: [
          false,
          "holiday",
          "New Year's Eve"
        ]
      }
    }
  };

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var result = [true, ""];
      var yr = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy", date),
        mo = $.datepicker.formatDate("m", date),
        dy = $.datepicker.formatDate("d", date);
      if (date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1) {
        result[0] = false;
      }
      if (holidays[yr] !== undefined) {
        if (holidays[yr][mo] !== undefined) {
          if (holidays[yr][mo][dy] !== undefined) {
            console.log("Holiday: " + mo + "/" + dy + "/" + yr);
            result = holidays[yr][mo][dy];
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.holiday span {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label><span style="color: #000080;"><strong>Your Appointment Date</strong></span>(required)</label><input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

As you didn't specify which holidays you needed, I copied some old code I had for another answer. This is more complex than is needed. You can simply have an array or dates.

In `beforeShowDay`, we assume all days will be `[true, ""]`. That way there is always something to return. We then test each day, looking for a day of the week that is `0` or `1` (Sunday or Monday) or looking for a day that has been defined as a Holiday. We then update our result array and return it.

**Update**

In your WP Code, you will want to ensure you are creating a Text Input and not a Date Input. Also all IDs must be unique, so if you have other `datepicker` id's you should consider changing them.

> Creating a datepicker on an `<input type="date">` is not supported due to a UI conflict with the native picker.

I would advise the following:

```
<label> <span style="color: #000080;"><strong>Your Appointment Date</strong></span>(required)</label>[text* date-163 id:datepicker]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.....Happy New Year!!! i tried this code but still not working.placed just after body in my header and even called through function file.it does display sun n mon...

Comment: @Amitkumar please provide more details. What is not working specifically? Are there errors in Console? I could not load the link you provided.

Comment: @Amitkumar also do you mean you do not want them to appear at all or just be disabled from selection (as they are currently).

Comment: @Amitkumar when I navigate to your website address, it does not load. It is also a realy bad idea to post any credentials online.

Comment: @Amitkumar are you sure you are using the code correctly? Do you see any errors in console when the page loads? When you click on the field. Did you adjust away fro m`date` type to `text`?

Comment: @Amitkumar it might be best to use PasteBin or something like that to Copy/Paste the resulting Source Code for review. Something is not adding up. I would also check PHP or WP for errors in your server logs.

Comment: but yes i got one part of my question

Answer (score 0):

First you need prepare array of holidays then try this one.

```
var holidays = ["2014-02-27","2014-02-01"];
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ holidays.indexOf(datestring) == -1 ]
}
});
```

Comment: Must return array that contains at least two values: `[0]`: `true`/`false` and `[1]`: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay Also this does not address OP's question about Sunday and Monday.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your script with this .. and append your holiday list in removeDays variable.

```
function disabledays(date) {
    var ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
        //if u have to disable a list of day
         var removeDays = ["2013-6-11","2013-6-31" ];
         if ($.inArray(ymd, removeDays) >= 0) {
        return [false];
    } else {
        //Show accept sundays
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 ||day == 5 ||day == 6 )];
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: disabledays
    });
});
```

If still it dont works then share your console error.

Comment: Might consider using the `$.datepicker.formatDate()` function: *Format a date into a string value with a specified format.* Use like so: `var ymd = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-m-d", date);` Might also stick to a RFC format like "yy-mm-dd" for dates in an array. Also return array must contain at least two values: `[0]`: `true`/`false` and `[1]`: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Answer (score 0):

got the answer....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Need to delete above script
one need to include jquery only once....adding above script along with

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

makes  $(...).datepicker null.

Comment: This is adding two different versions of jQuery and is not advised.